# TortoiseSVN with VisualSVN server

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I am trying to set up a Online Repository for my work because multiple people from different locations need to be abled to acces the files and be abled to commit to it.

Now i have set up the Visual SVN server on my VPS. But i have no idea how Tortoise SVN works and how i can commit to my repository on my VPS server. I am using tortoise SVN plugin in atom. But when i try to commit there is no project at all where i can commit to. Even though there is a project in my project manager that is connected to my VisualSVN server.

Can anyone tell me how to get this all to work with two users, making changes to 1 repository and everytime they commit the differences between files are checked and certain things are added, or removed.

Comment: Why are you not using Git?

Comment: Because how do you manage two users on a single git repository? I am new to this version controlling thing

Comment: Please read up about git. You can manage a good few hundred under git

Comment: Could you give me a link on how i can set up git for multiple users?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308485/setting-up-git-server-on-windows